# How to work around having a session field in page_load?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form that utilize two pages, one is a main page, and the other is a page that you can get to via a `Response.Redirect` on my main page or you can simply navigate to it by knowing the URL. However, since I have

```
int field4 = (int)(Session["field4"]); //flag to see if the source page redirected to the override page
```

in my `Page_Load` method on my second page, if I don't get there from the first page by setting the session field equal to a value before hand then I get a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always Check for `NULL` for state Variables like `ViewState,Session,Application`,etc

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
if(Session["field4"]!=null)
int field4 = (int)(Session["field4"]);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to convert null value to type int,
So in page load Check First

```
    if (Session["field4"]!=null )
    {
        int field4 = (int)(Session["field4"]); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check that the session variable has been set, (and hence the value returned by the key is not equal to `null`).

If you are not doing any processing with the value in `field4`, you could do:

```
bool didUserArriveViaTheHomePage = (Session["field4"] != null);
```

If you need the value, you could check if the cast is possible using the [`as` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) prior to casting, or you could use a [nullable int](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).